# After latest update, Avast says tor's firefox.exe has IDP.Generic virus/trojan

Tags: firefox

After latest update, Avast says tor's firefox.exe has IDP.Generic virus/trojan. Does it? How can I be sure it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, this is common. A false-positive. Anti-virus is a bad idea and you should avoid using it if possible. [More on that here](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/guide.md#anti-virus).

Comment: When I tried to open pubg on my pc, Avast is stopping and showing the error “IDP.Generic” warning then I have tried fixing it by searching on google for a solution. I found this and found helpful. Here is the link: https://winerrorfixer.com/idp-generic/

Answer (score 1):

Well, using antivirus when using Tor is a **bad practice** - but if you need this(sometimes it has it's uses and the problems AV makes are counterweighted by the tasks it solves) - use a proper antivirus. I do **not** recommend using Avas, Eset(NOD32 and other crap from them), Kaspersky(it spies on you in open, it's a malware, not antivirus), Symantec and Panda. What I do recommend is BitDefender and Sophos(enterprise version). But **only** if you **really** need it and you know what you're doing!

Comment: sorry, but your advice that "Anti-virus is a bad idea and you should avoid using it if possible." sounds completely ridiculous and exactly what someone who wants you to use their malware would say! Has tor been compromised?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13714)

Comment: @Alexey Vesnin Do you mean to say that it is bad practice because the antivirus it's not configured to properly route is traffic through TOR? I believe that you may be referring to an antivirus with an internet security suite (firewall, ect). A plain old AV will only, to my knowledge, scan your computer for malicious software, though one with an internet security suite will attempt to block what it deems to be malware coming from a website or server from connecting to you. Basically, if it thinks it's maleate coming from a website then it'll block from connecting to you. I don't believe a plai

Comment: AV is a rootkit controlled by people you don't know, who watch *everything* that you do on the computer for "suspicious" activity. If they spot it, it gets reported to them. If you have strong privacy or anonymity requirements from someone with subpoena power, or you might be targeted by sophisticated hackers, then you shouldn't use AV. If you're just using it to read the news and avoid trackers profiling you for ads, and you want to avoid getting hit with the latest strain of ransomware from a malicious email attachment, then AV might be appropriate to use.

Comment: Also, this isn't an answer, this is a comment on another answer.